# Warning: Converting to Boxing Syntax requires casting 'long' to 'int'

Tags: objective-c, warnings, nsnumber

Any idea how to get this warning to go away. The code runs fine, I just don't like warnings in my project. I have never come across this warning before so I am making a mountain out of a mole hill I think. Boxing syntax? Is that referring to the square brackets? This warning shows up when trying to modernize an old project in Objective-C using Xcode.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {

   [sequence addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:random()% 6]]; 

}
```

It throws an error stating:

Converting to boxing syntax requires casting 'long' to 'int'

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Boxing" refers to the new syntax for boxing C expressions, e.g.

```
NSNumber *n = @(2*3+4)
```

instead of

```
NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(2*3+4)];
```

(see http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html for details).

In your case,

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:random()% 6]
```

creates a number object containing an `int`, but

```
@(random()% 6)
```

would create a number object containing a `long`, because `random()` is declared as

```
long random(void);
```

So to get exactly the same behavior as before the conversion, you would have to write

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)(random()% 6)]
```

which is then converted to

```
@((int)(random()% 6))
```

If you don't care which "flavor" of number object you get, then just convert that line
manually to

```
[sequence addObject:@(random()% 6)];
```

but Xcode cannot decide that for you.

Comment: thanks man, this makes perfect sense. In fact I should have realized this myself since I was in the process of converting the line to modernized Objective-C. I have no excuses for myself. Long day maybe? Thanks again.